# Cannot publish an action required to submit it to create an FB app

Tags: facebook, action, publish

I have created an facebook app, took built-in action (read) and object (article), also back at my web site properly inserted meta og: tags, only thing left to do is to publish at leaste one action to my timeline and submit my action, but every time I try "https://graph.facebook.com/me/namespace:read?article=correctURL&access_token="access token copied from the "Get code" dialog at Open graph settings", and it returns me this message

{

"error": {

"message": "Unknown path components: /appnamespace:read",

"type": "OAuthException",

"code": 2500

}

}

Is this a facebook bug at the moment, or am I just doing something wrong here? Is there any precise way to deal with this?

Comment: if it's a built-in action i don't think you need the appnamespace: part, do you?

Answer (score 1):

According with the "Get code" dialog at Open graph settings, the uri should be

https://graph.facebook.com/me/**news.reads**?article="...."&access_token="..."

The namespace should be used only with custom actions.

Comment: Did you _leave out_ the namespace?